# JBoss wildfly 10 doesn't reach a servlet

Tags: servlets, jboss, jboss-wildfly-11

After years using Spring MVC's controllers on Tomcat and Weblogic I have to create a simple Servlet, without the help of any Framework, to run under **JBOSS wildfly 10**. I miss a step to make it works under JBoss. Under Tomcat it works.

This is my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    }
...
}
```

My WEB.XML file is empty.

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <servlet>  
 <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>com.de.simple.HelloWorld</servlet-class>  
 </servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>  
    </web-app>
```

When I try to run the servlet under JBoss, I don't get any error. Simply, when I go to http://localhost:8080/simple/HelloWorld I get:
`The webpage cannot be found`

What is the step I need to implement on Jboss?
Thank you

Comment: You don't need to define anything in the web.xml. Is the name of your WAR `simple.war`?

Comment: I removed the content of web.xml and it worked. Thank you